# How to replace null with string when column is of datatype int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns and sample data like this:

[image]

All columns are of datatype `int`.

I have this query :

```
select 
    foodid, dayid 
from 
    Schedule
```

I want replace `dayid` with a string if `dayid=null` .

For this I tried this query :

```
select 
    foodid,
    Dayid + ISNULL(dayid,'not day') 
from Schedule
```

but I am getting this ERROR :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'not day' to data type int.

How can do this ?

Comment: Please post the desired results based on your sample data.

Comment: `I want replace dayid with a string id dayid=null ` it will be null so what different you want?

Comment: Specify your RDBMS,.

Comment: Try  `select foodid,ISNULL(dayid,'not day') from Schedule` In your query you are trying to add (dayid + ...).

Comment: @PM77-1 Scheduleid is primary key , and other fileds are foreign key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try with  this:

```
select foodid, ISNULL(str(dayid),'not day') from Schedule
```