# How to replace null value of fields by a string in the query

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a table named visits in where I save visited pages. It contains a column named user_id , if the user is authenticated I save his id else I set it null.

I'd like to replace all **user_id null** by a word **"visitor"** inside the query.

Based in this sql example [How to replace null with string when column is of datatype int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795668/how-to-replace-null-with-string-when-column-is-of-datatype-int?answertab=active#tab-top) I have make this query:

```
 // ..............
 $builder->select('visits.*', DB::raw("ISNULL(str(user_id), Visitor) as name"));
```

But I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select `visits`.*, ISNULL(str(user_id), Visitor) as name from `visits`

Comment: It will be `IFNULL`, not `ISNULL`

Comment: After a long period

Comment: "After a long period", I saw your answer since the first day , and because I don't forget the people who help me even before a year, I wrote a reply to thank you ;)